# Override local files with the ones of a specific branch

Tags: git

I have a git server with some branches:

```
    $ git log
commit 03a870730a0273f354236b4d724c4f3379b6d182
Author: Giovanni Antonioni <antonioni.giovanni9@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Jun 5 13:31:55 2015 +0200

    Description 1

commit 4435b7718609c3622542b6b2a8d7a59994083044
Author: Giovanni Antonioni <antonioni.giovanni9@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Jun 5 10:30:59 2015 +0200

    Description 2

commit 8a8bafdd6e0879b5ef726db13e786caffc65fb13
Author: Giovanni Antonioni <antonioni.giovanni9@gmail.com>
Date:   Thu Jun 4 17:47:19 2015 +0200

    Description 3

commit 3dddec8764330250cf7d57e2d18957e568a64c36
Author: Giovanni Antonioni <antonioni.giovanni9@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Jun 1 15:47:42 2015 +0200
```

I need to bring my project status to the first branch (3dddec87) and delete the other. How can i do from terminal?

Comment: Those are commits, not branches. A branch is a sequence of commits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of [`git log`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) that you provided doesn't say anything about [branches](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell). It displays the last four commits on the current branch.

If you really want to bring the project to the state it had on commit `3dddec87` then you can use [`git reset --hard`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset)

```
git reset --hard 3dddec87
```

This command discards the three commits you did after `3dddec87`. It brings everything (working tree, index, current branch) in the state they were immediately after you created commit `3dddec87`.

#### How to play safe

**Before** doing `git reset --hard` you can create a new branch (I named it `backup`) that points to your current `HEAD`:

```
git branch backup
```

It serves as a backup in case you do something wrong.

If you not are satisfied how the things look like after you do `git reset --hard`, you can return back where you were using `git merge backup` or `git reset --hard backup`.

But if you **are** satisfied and you decide you really don't need the first three commits from the listing you can delete the `backup` branch using:

```
git branch -D backup
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to reset your branch back to that commit (discarding the later commits). In that case, you can do

```
git reset --hard 3dddec87
```

This sets both your branch and working copy to the specified commit.

You can use `git reflog` and another `git reset` command to undo this change.

Comment: But note that `git reset --hard` is a dangerous command. Do not use it unless you understand and accept the consequences.

Answer (score 1):

It's can be done via

```
git checkout <commit>
```

So for you it will be

```
git checkout 3dddec8764330250cf7d57e2d18957e568a64c36
```

Of course if you want discarding local changes you can do, but be careful with it :

```
git reset --hard 3dddec8764330250cf7d57e2d18957e568a64c36
```

The second variant is better, because it's avoid ending up in 
[detached head.](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#_detached_head)

Thanks to RJFalconer for comment.

Comment: It would be better to move the branch HEAD (with `git reset`) rather than `git checkout <sha1>`, to avoid ending up in [detatched head](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#_detached_head)